# What is the difference between ~다면서 and ~다며

Tags: grammar, difference, verb-endings

Lately I have been listening to the song 좋아 that 민서 sings. The first part of the song goes:

이제 괜찮니 너무 힘들었다며 너의 그 마무리가 고작 이별뿐일 거라 우린 괜찮다면서

I was wondering if someone could explain to me the usage difference between ~다면서 and ~다며. I know this is a SONG so it will be more poetic and less conversational, but I am a stickler and really want to understand the nuances behind everything :)

땡큐~

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/when-would-i-use-면서-vs-며 is an existing question about this topic - but it doesn't yet have an accepted answer. Perhaps a good answer to this question would focus on the meaning in the song?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was also asking when 면서 and 며 are attached to "다" : I'm not sure if this would change the meaning at all as well.

Comment: '~다며/~다면서'는 의미상으로는 큰 차이가 없는 것 같습니다. 서로 혼용해서 써도 무리가 없을 것 같습니다.

Comment: 참고로 위의 가사를 "너무 힘들었다면서"로 바꿔도 의미상 전혀 문제가 없습니다

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi random Korean passing by :D
Your question is reeeeealllllly tricky.....

그는 A다면서 B했다. : He did  B, even though A.
 (OR the same meaning as below)

그는 A다며 B했다. : He did B, saying/doing/etc A.

So, 다면서 has more various meanings and uses than 다며.
Both are usually used in spoken language or when explaining a certain situation.

OMG this is so hard to explain. The best way to get a feel of nuances is to actually talk with native speakers, I think.....     r(ㅇㅅㅇ )

Answer (score 2):

To add more details to the other answers, there is indeed a sense of continuity when saying 다며 but when you say ~한다면서 there is also a sense of negativity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I search 다며, 다면서 in Korean dictionary

다며 : contraction of 다면서

다면서 : (1) 직접 간접으로 들은 사실을 다짐 (check)

A heard that clothes of the shop had fascinating colors. So today A buy several clothes

by saying to the host that clothes has a beautiful color.

A는 그 가게 옷이 좋다는 것을 들었다. 그래서 오늘 주인에게 옷 색이 좋**다면서** 몇벌 샀다.

(2) 빈정거림 (negative attitude)

Even though you studied hard, did you fail in the examination ?

너 공부했**다면서**, 시험을 망했니 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the above Korean comment. His answer is not the correct answer to this question. This phrase is hard to explain the nuance, but I'm sure my comments are the most accurate.

"다며" is just a contraction of "다면서".

If you use "다면서" in a plain form, it means "You said that~",
but if you use it in a questionable form, it means "I heard that~".

So,
"너 잠 잤다면서", "너 잠 잤다며" means "You said you slept".

But,
"너 밥 먹었다면서?", "너 밥 먹었다며?" means "I heard you ate".